# Has the solidarity tax been successful in any country?

Tags: economy, taxes, europe

I have recently saw an older recording of an economist arguing that he does not know of any "successful implementation" of the solidarity tax. I have searched a little bit about this and found [this article](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/solidarity-tax.asp) which mentions the criticism related to the implementation of this tax in France:

> The solidarity tax has been criticized by many who believe it drives
>   away the wealthy from France or incentivizes the rich to find ways to
>   evade taxes.

I am wondering the economist is right.

**Question:** Has the solidarity tax been successful in any country?

To make the question more answerable (clear, not too broad):

- successful = the collected amount > estimated loss through wealth being moved outside the country + estimation of tax evasion + cost of collection
- European country
- no special context such as warfare, German reunification or similar events
- after WWII

Comment: Can you precise what you consider as "solidarity tax" ? Many (most?) taxes include solidarity as one of their justification. Your exemple seem to be the French "Impôt sur la fortune" ("tax on fortune"), which is a tax on rich people *assets* (and not *income*), is this what you are interested in ?

Comment: @Evargalo - yes, I am interested in tax on assets or similar.

Comment: @Alexei: please could you put that in your question.

Comment: I think you could expand this to include wealth confiscation in general, i.e. after socialist/communist takeovers, and still be on safe grounds.

Comment: The main problem to answer this question is that by definition the amount of lost wealth *due to the tax* is almost impossible to estimate: it's practically impossible to establish a clear causation link between the existence of a tax and people/money moving out of a country, since this can happen for many other reasons. That's why this kind of question often leads to debates which are more ideological than based on facts.

Comment: Note that there is already a very successful implicit wealth tax; it's called inflation.  Buy property for the value of a million loaves of bread, say a million dollars, wait a few years, sell it for the same value of a million loaves of bread, now worth 1.5 million dollars, and you'll be taxed on the non-existent .5 million capital gains profit you made.

Comment: @Alexei if you want answers instead of comments, I hope you clarify if you mean solidarity tax a la investopedia (like a reconstruction tax in Japan after the 2011 tsunami) or e.g. like that of my native Finland (where it was launched a decade ago to further increase the tax rate of those with high income, on top of the originally strong tax progression)

Comment: @Tuomo - Finland's model is the most fit as Japan's reconstruction is an effect of I called a special context (nuclear disasters are really rare in highly developed countries).

Comment: I would be surprised if any tax failed your "success" criteria.  But that's not usually what people talk about when they talk about "success".  If you pass a wealth tax claiming it will raise $100 billion but because of people moving away or employing other tax avoidance strategies the government only gets $5 billion in additional revenue, it would be a huge political failure but would appear to count as a success under your criteria.

Comment: Note that the article is wrong for the solidarity tax in Germany: It was started to finance Germany's price for the Gulf War. The second installation was somehow for East Germany, but that's dubious.

Comment: You really need to define your criteria for success.  I'd certainly think that state-run lotteries would count: they're a voluntary tax, and (at least in the US) have been sold to voters as providing funding for education &c.